# Jquery How to replace HTML after specific element?

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple layout, part of it is as follows:

```
<td class="subset">
<form name="searchFrm" method="get" action="update.php">
<input type="text" name="search">
</form>

html 
html
html

</td>
```

I want to replace everything after the `form` up to the `td` with new html loaded from a PHP Page.

eg:
Changing it to:

```
<td class="subset">
<form name="searchFrm" method="get" action="update.php">
<input type="text" name="search">
</form>

New HTML from PHP

</td>
```

I know I can select the form using `$( '[name="searchFrm"]' )` and load an external page using `.load('new.php')` but how do I remove the HTML after the form and then add the new html ?

I tried

```
$( '[name="searchFrm"]' ).after().load('new.php')
```

Which didn't help, is there any way to do this ?
I'm not trying to add or remove individual rows, but replace HTML after an element with in a row.

Updated post with correct form name.

Thanks

Comment: Can there also be content before the form that you want to keep ?

Comment: Why not wrap the contents after the form in an element with an id so you can target it directly ?

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli - In this specific `td` there is nothing before the `form`. There are other rows before and after this one. I have no control over some of the code so can't add new elements etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add/remove HTML inside div using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17650776/add-remove-html-inside-div-using-javascript)

Comment: HI, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27538239/10606400) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all a note, the `$('[name="search"]')` will not select just the `form` but the `input` as well since it also has the same `name` value. So use `$('form[name="search"]')`.

There are a couple of approaches to tackle your issue.

One is the [answer of @pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66688050/128165) which re-writes the form html along with the new content.

Some problems with this approach are

- The exact posted code also suffers from the missing `form` in the selector and will therefore remove the `form` tag from the result.
- if you later add some contents before the `form` (*in the same `td`*) it will stop working (*it will remove that content*)
- if there are attached handlers on the form or any of its descendants, they will be lost, as `.html` only keeps the html text and not anything attached through code.
- it will also not work directly with `.load`. But you can work around that with `$.ajax`

---

Another more involved solution, but much safer, is to go through the pain of selecting the actual nodes after the `form`.

To do this you need to use `.contents` which is the only jQuery method that returns `textNodes` as well.

A verbose implementation (*so you can see each step*) could be

```js
function replaceContentsAfterForm(newUrl) {
  const form = $('form[name="search"]'); // select the form only
  const formParent = form.parent(); // get the form container
  const contents = [...formParent.contents()]; // select the contents of the container in an array
  const formIndex = contents.indexOf(form[0]); // find where the form is in the array 
  const afterForm = contents.slice(formIndex + 1); // select everything after the form
  const placeholder = $('<div id="placeholder" />'); // create a temporary placeholder to contain the data after the form
  placeholder.append(afterForm); // fill the placeholder with the contents after the form
  form.after(placeholder); // put the placeholder after the form in the DOM

  $(placeholder).load(newUrl, function() { // load the new content
    placeholder.replaceWith(placeholder.contents()) // and finally remove the placeholder eleemnt
  })
}

// and you can call it with
replaceContentsAfterForm('new.php');
```

Comment: I've realised a typo in the code I posted. The form is actually called `searchFrm` I've updated the code to be `const form = $('form[name="searchFrm"]'); // select the form only`

When I run the code I get `Uncaught TypeError: formParent.contents is not a function or its return value is not iterable`

Comment: @Tom what jquery version are you using ? can you log what `formParent` and `formParent.contents()` return ?

Comment: I'm running v1.8.0 :( I hadn't realised it was that old. What is the required version for this to work ?

Comment: @Tom it needs 2.2 at least, since that is when iterators where added. You can alternatively replace `const contents = [...formParent.contents()];` with `const contents = Array.from(formParent.contents());` Example at https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/bqLpk4vc/5/

Answer (score 0):

Change parent element content by `form + new content`.

```js
var form = $('[name=search]');
var parent = form.parent();

parent.html(form.html() + 'new HTML content');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td class="subset">
    <form name="search" method="get" action="update.php">
        <input type="text" name="search">
    </form>

    html 
    html
    html

</td>
```

Comment: This would remove any handlers attached to the form or any of its descendants.

Comment: @pavel - how do I load the new html ? I'd normally use `.load('new.php')`